# concurrent calls using spring webflux and hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, hystrix

hoping someone can steer me in the right direction in turning my code into a more reactive service call. for background I have a preceding function that will generate a list of users, will then use that list to call this getUserDetails function for each user in the list, and return a map or list of user + details.

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey = "getUserDetails")
  public getUserResponse getUserDetails(userRequest request) {
    getUserResponse response = webClient.post()
        .uri(uri)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, resp -> resp.bodyToMono(getUserError.class).map(errorHandler::mapRequestErrors))
        .bodyToMono(getUserResponse.class).block();

    return response;
  }
```

Ideally I would also replace/remove the error mapping as only concerned with logging the returned error response and continuing.
so far I have thought something along the lines of this but I'm not sure the webflux/hystrix will play nice?

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey = "getUserDetails", fallbackMethod = "getUserFallback")
  public Mono<getUserResponse> getUserDetails(userRequest request) {
    return = webClient.post()
        .uri(uri)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(getUserResponse.class);
  }

  @HystrixCommand
  public Mono<getUserResponse> getUserFallback(userRequest request, Throwable throwable) {
    log.error(//contents of error message returned)
    return mono.empty();
  }

public Flux<UserMap> fetchUserDetails(List<Integer> userIds) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(userIds)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .flatMap(userDetailsRepository::getUserDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix is deprecated. If you have a chance, move to [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j) which has support for Webflux/Reactor.

[Spring](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) also has dedicated support for resilience4j.

Regarding error handling you can leverage the rich set of operators from the Mono/Flux API like `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResume`.

Comment: thanks! been playing around with it. It's probably because spring-boot2 hides the implementation details, but as far as I can tell so long as the repo method (getUserDetails) and/or its wrapping class are annotated with circuit-breaker, etc the calling flux doesn't need any specific circuit-breaker decoration?

Comment: Yes, in our Spring Boot 2 module the CircuitBreakerAspect is handling this for you. The Aspect checks the return type of your method and if the return type is Flux/Mono it uses the CircuitBreakerOperator to protect it.